# Frequent GC on young gen

Tags: java, garbage-collection

How much ever i allocate for eden space, GC is being invoked frequently on young gen space.
Following were my JVM parameter
-Xmx2g
-Xms512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M.

I tried giving following parameters so to give enough space for young gen
-Xmn3g
-Xmx8g
-XX:SurvivorRatio=15
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
-Xms6g
-XX:NewRatio=1

But no luck.
I am getting this problem while using Java compiler API to generate a compiled class file 
dynamically. With large java file objects, this compilation task is taking upto 1.5gb of young gen space. GC on young gen space is being invoked even though it has even space left.
My code used to work perfectly fine. I bumped into this problem all of a sudden with out any reason.
Could any one please help me out of this problem?

Comment: What is the JDK version and plateform that you are using ?

Comment: I was using jdk1.6.20 and i tried with jdk 1.6.45 and jdk1.7.0_60 but no use. using windows 7.

Comment: try following combination -Xmx4g -Xms2g -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:SurvivorRatio=10 -XX:NewRatio= 2

Comment: Tried it..but no use. I feel that this might be something related to Fragmented heap space of jvm.